# Hello. I want to ask a question about how to solve to integrate multiple projects in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, integration, conflict

I want to integrate multiple projects in Unity, but it have a lot of file conflicts. I would like to know is there a way can indenpent unity each project folder, and then they are not conflicts. Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: look into setting each project up as a unity package, then use the package manager in the main project to import all the other projects

Comment: A) use different namespaces for your scripts B) instead of putting everything under `Assets` rather put it under `Assets/projectName`. This way you should have neither compilation nor system file path conflicts ... Then make sure all your projects have the same Unity version and you have installed the packages required by each if them. May ask **why** though?

Comment: Thanks for answers, I export a unity package for each project and defined assembly for them, created package.json file. I integrated 2 unity packages, the compiler don't show fault message, but the same MenuItem of the 2 unity packages  have a lot of conflicts. Is there a perfect way to solve these conflicts？Tranks again.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to construct projects in a way that makes it easier, once the conflict lands, its just damage control